# Setting up a CSS Grid systems to allow for different number of items

Tags: css, sass, css-grid

I am trying to setup a grid systems using CSS and SASS that allows for a different number of items to be proportionally spaced within its container, see image below:

[image]

The grid is 4 x 2 as you can appreciate so I need to find a way to span, fill or fit the column and rows to fill the space but since I'm learning its proven to be a challenge for me, I have a [codepen](https://codepen.io/nardove/pen/BaKqVmr?editors=1100) with poor results, any advise will be much appreciated.

Here is my codepen "code":

```css
* {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
}
.container {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px 0;
    
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    
    grid-template-rows: fit-content(180px);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(180px, 2fr));
}

.item {
    background-color: orangered;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr) ` seems to be what you need,

Comment: Is [this](https://jsbin.com/fisehivoqi/1/edit?html,css,output) what you want?

Comment: @yousaf yes but I'm looking to reuse code, since this data is coming from a json file, so I wonder if it is at all possible by using the same CSS classes?, I can do it using JS but then it will be a bit of a pain when it come to make it responsive

Comment: You can't make a reusable grid if the number of items in the grid is different each time and the grid layout itself varies. If the layout stays the same then you can create a grid layout that adapts to different number of items in the grid..

Comment: @Yousaf correct so I'll work my layout based on that principle, thank you all for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ?

```css
.container {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 10px;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    
    /* Start with 4 columns to make it easier */
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.item {
    padding:10px;
    font-size:30px;
    background-color: orangered;
    grid-column: span 2;
}

/* spans the first element when there's only 3 */
.item:nth-last-child(3) {
    grid-row: span 2;
}

/* Selects the second element when there's 4 (the element we selected above) and rest it's grid span */
.item:nth-last-child(4) + .item {
    grid-row: span 1;
}

/* Spans the first element when there's 5 elements */
.item:nth-last-child(5) {
    grid-row: span 2;
}

/* Resets the column span of the rest of the elements when there's 5 elements */
.item:nth-last-child(5)~div {
    grid-column: span 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems that what I'm trying to achieve is not possible, if the list of items is 6 or more them the CSS wont work, but this answer does solve my problem.